# Why does my query to AWS Keyspaces using the Cassandra Python driver return an empty list?

Tags: cassandra, amazon-keyspaces, datastax-python-driver

I am trying to use a prepared statement to query keyspaces via python's cassandra driver.

This is the query and it's preparation...

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

cluster = Cluster(
    **conn_details
)
            
session = cluster.connect("mykeyspace")

query = ("SELECT timestamp "  
        "FROM mykeyspace.mytable "
        "WHERE t_id='123' "
        "AND p_id='321' "
        "AND timestamp IN ? "
        )

prepared_statement = session.prepare(query)

session.execute(prepared_statement, parameters=[ (1677145736507, 1677145728972) ]).current_rows
```

The output is an empty list. There is some issue with the statement binding as I'm able to run the CQL IN with success in three scenarios below... i.e. if I run the below raw query via `session.execute(<raw query string>)` I can get a response..

```
SELECT timestamp
FROM mykeyspace.mytable 
WHERE t_id='123'
AND p_id='321' 
AND collection_event_timestamp IN (1677145728972, 1677145736507)
```

If I run inside the keyspaces query editor on AWS I get the expected response

[image]

The only way I can get IN to work with any parameterisation is via string formatting..

```
id_tuples = (1677145736507, 1677145728972)

query = "SELECT timestamp FROM mykeyspace.mytable WHERE t_id='123' AND p_id='321' AND timestamp IN %s  "

session.execute(query, parameters=[ValueSequence(id_tuples)]).current_rows
```

[image]

Does anyone have any advice as to what is going wrong here? Why is the prepared statement approach not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a prepared statement in Python using the `IN` operator, you'll need to define your variable as a dictionary instead of a tuple:

```
pStatement = session.prepare("""
    SELECT * FROM sales.emp WHERE empid IN ?;
""")

employees = {99, 68}

rows = session.execute(pStatement,[employees])
print("Employee data:\n")
for row in rows:
    print(row)


% python testDBIN.py

Employee data:

Row(empid=99, first_name='Wayne', last_name='Gretzky')
Row(empid=68, first_name='Jaromir', last_name='Jagr')
```

> Does IN only work on partition columns? I'm trying to filter on a clustering column

Ok, so that means that your're trying to run a query which the table wasn't built to support.  The `IN` operator does work on both partition and clustering columns.

But, it only works on clustering columns IF all preceeding keys are also specified.  I don't see your table definition above, but I do see that you're filtering on `t_id` and `p_id`.  No idea if those are the preceeding keys in the PRIMARY KEY definition or not.

The other possibility, is that perhaps this is one of those areas where Amazon Keyspaces != Apache Cassandra.  Seeing syntax and programatic approaches that work in Cassandra but fail in Keyspaces is quite common.  Unfortunately, the two are not 100% compatible.

Comment: No luck with this @Aaron

`prepared_statement = session.prepare(query)` and then execution

`session.execute(prepared_statement, ["org-vjr4fbyj-ey8mqkep-2yb06qyaj-jxat4gzv","abc",{1677145736507, 1677145728972}],).current_rows` this returns empty list still

Comment: Does IN only work on partition columns? I'm trying to filter on a clustering column

Comment: @SamComber Edit made.  This may be one of those limitations with Keyspaces.